# android buttons not working

Tags: android

I am really new to android and java and have so far been doing video tutorials. However on my first attempt at my own code none of the `Buttons` seem to respond to anything am I doing, is something wrong?

I have done several similar codes and copy and pasted some examples and in all the examples when running on android phone and tablet none of the `Buttons` do anything.

```
public class Two extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button showa;
    EditText et1;
    TextView ans1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.two);

        methodInit();
        showa.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void methodInit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        ans1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans1);


    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.button1:
        String check = et1.getText().toString();
        et1.setText(check);
        if (check.contains("4")){
            ans1.setText("correct!!!");
                break;
        }

    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are you using onclick function of button?

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.two);
    methodInit();       
   }
    private void methodInit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       showa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
       ans1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans1);
       showa.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

    public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.button1:
          String check = et1.getText().toString();
          et1.setText(check);
          if (check.contains("4")){
          ans1.setText("correct!!!");
         break;
      }
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will not work, you currently have `showa.setOnClickListener(this);` outside of all the methods.

Answer (score 0):

After a second look at your code, i notice that you **ARE** actually setting the `onClickListener`... the code i posted below, works for me. Try it and see what happens.

---

You need to set the `onClickListener` on your `Button`.

Take a look at the following code:

```
public class Two extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button showa;
    private EditText et1;
    private TextView ans1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.two);

        methodInit();
    }
    private void methodInit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        ans1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans1);
        showa.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.button1:
            String check = et1.getText().toString();
            et1.setText(check);
            if (check.contains("4")){
                ans1.setText("correct!!!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```